# mssql generating unique code

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, recursion

please help me in this,how would i do some recursive statement in my stored procedure.
here is what i want

```
-- @requestcode will genereate some random string i have already the code below

set @requestcode = (SELECT substring(@username,0,3)+'-'+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), 0, 9))

-- then i want to check if the string generated is existing to 'sampletable'
select @requestcode from sampletable

-- if it is existing back to the @requestcode query until it is not existing
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@requestcode` starts as NULL (unless assigned already) so the first WHILE condition check is always true which gives at least one iteration

```
WHILE @requestcode IS NULL OR
        EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sampletable WHERE requestcode = @requestcode)
BEGIN
    SELECT @requestcode = substring(@username,0,3) + '-' + 
           SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), 0, 9));
END
```